# Where Can I Legally Find Sword Art Online Alicization English Dubbed For Free

Tags: sword-art-online

I was just wondering where I can find Sword Art Online Alicization in English dubbed for free legally.

I tried searching on Google; I found an article that said to look on Aniplex. All I found on Aniplex's website was a picture of the SAO Season 3 cover, and when I clicked on that it brought me to a website that had a option to buy the season.

If anyone has a link to a website where I can watch SAO Season 3 English dubbed for free, or can tell me there is no such website, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The English Dub is licensed by Funimation and currently can only be legally streamed through their own video platform, in regions where it is licensed to be streamed. You may be able to watch the full season through the two-week trial period.

Previous seasons' dub tracks have been added to Crunchyroll, so it's possible that the Alicization seasons could also be added in the future, and could be streamed there for free. (The ads inserted are what fund the ability for you to watch it free.) Currently, however, Crunchyroll only offers the subtitled version.